# How to tell Camel to wait until the end of the copy?

Tags: java, apache-camel

When a hudge file is beeing copied to a repository, Camel start processing before the end of the copy.

This is my route définition :

```
file:C:/data?include=[A-Z]{3}_01.*\.eee$&delete=true&moveFailed=C:/data/error
```

If my *eee* filesize is > 50Mo, i've got an error during processing..

How to tell Camel to wait until the end of the copy of the file?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read the documentation first. See that big box on the top of this page, with the title *Avoid reading files currently being written by another application*

- https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html

Comment: I already tried the readLock like it's specified in the documentation, w/o success with "changed" and "fileLock" mode.
It's now OK with "rename" mode. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `initialDelay` and `delay` to solve this issue.

`initialDelay` is the time before the files start to be consumed.

`delay` is the time between polls of the directory.

Please see the [File2 documentation](http://camel.apache.org/file2) for more information.

Comment: I can't set initial delay because the size will change and i can't predict the delay